# How to pass arguments in double quotes inside bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

normally use these 3 commands to push my code to repo

```
git add .
git commit -m $1
git push -u git@myrepo.git  master
```

I tried to put all 3 commands in a script and thereby execute them together

I tried with ./upload_to_github.sh "minor change"

```
#!/bin/bash
#upload_to_github.sh
git add .
git commit -m $1
git push -u git@myrepo.git  master
```

it gives error

```
error: pathspec 'change' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

I as well tried the following one but of no use

```
#!/bin/bash
#upload_to_github.sh
git add .
git commit -m \"$1\"
git push -u git@myrepo.git  master
```

which gives me the error

```
error: pathspec '"change\""' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

both of them doesn't seem to be working. How do I pass my $1 along with double quotes inside the script?

Comment: To pass the value quoted, use `"$1"`. To pass the value quoted, and with quotes in the value itself, use `"\"$1\""`, but I don't see why you'd want that.

Comment: I would be curious to know why do you not consider using such a script as useful.

Comment: Because you'd still need to escape any quotes from the original parameter. Just putting quotes at the start and end of it doesn't make it safe (to clarify, I'm talking about the double-quoting case here). In your case though, I think you only need the `"$1"` version, no?

Comment: thats true but even if I pass it with commit directly from command line I would have to escape. if my commit message has double quotes, independent of combining all 3 commands, I  would have to escape the double quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are encountering is word splitting.

What you should do is:

```
git commit -m "$1"
```

And then you call your script like

```
./upload_to_github 'minor change'
```

To understand the way it works I suggest you to read this: [Bash pitfall #2](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cp_.24file_.24target) which points to [Word splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) and [Glob](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) articles. Read these as well.

Answer (score 2):

Or, in your script use

```
git commit -m "$*"
```

and then you can invoke the script without needing to quote the arguments:

```
./upload_to_github this is a minor change
```

The `$*` parameter, when quoted (`"$*"`) joins all the positional parameters as a single string, using the first char of `IFS` (a space, unless redefined) as the separator. http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters

Comment: Yeah, that would work as well, however it might create a false sense of security for some people. ``./upload_to_github Asterisk *`` and BOOM!